# Converting CSV file to JSON clientside and displaying it in a table

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, csv

I am trying to convert a csv file to json object and then displaying it on the page. Currently I am taking the csv file from File Upload control and reading its data and displaying it on screen. But I now need to first convert that csv data to JSON and then display it on screen.

Below is my code for displaying csv file data on screen --

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>  

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Japan Automation</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h2>ABCD</h2>
            <p>EFG</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">IJKL</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-1">
                        <div class="page-header">
                            <h2>DIS Automation</h2>
                        </div>
                        <form id="form1" runat="server" class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6"><input type="file" accept=".csv" id="fileUpload" /></div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="button" id="upload" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload" /></div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="button" id="validate" class="btn btn-primary" value="Validate" /></div>   
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="button" id="cancel" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="Cancel" /></div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="button" id="update" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update Invalid PO" /></div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="button" id="process" class="btn btn-primary" value="Process" /></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-sm-12">   
                    <div class="panel panel-default" style="align-self:center">
                      <div class="panel-body" style="max-height: 400px;min-height:400px;overflow-y: scroll;">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-sm-12"><center>
                                                        <div class="input-append">
                                                          <input name="search" id="search" placeholder="Enter PO to filter"/>
                                                             <input type="button" value="Filter" id="filter" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                                                </div></center></div>

                        </div>     
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-sm-12" id="dvCSV">

                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

         </div>


</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript.js -**

```
function Upload() {
    var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
    if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var table = document.createElement("table");
                var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                    var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                    for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                        cell.innerHTML = cells[j];
                    }
                }
                var dvCSV = document.getElementById("dvCSV");
                dvCSV.innerHTML = "";
                dvCSV.appendChild(table);
            }
            reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0]);
        } else {
            alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
        }
    } else {
        alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");               
    }
}
```

**Javascript2.js**

```
$(function () {
    $("#upload").bind("click", function () {
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
        if (regex.test($("#fileUpload").val().toLowerCase())) {
            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var table = $("<table />");
                    var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        var row = $("<tr />");
                        var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                        $("<td />").html('<input type="checkbox" hidden="false"/>').appendTo(row);
                        table.append(row);
                        for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                            var cell = $("<td />");
                            cell.html(cells[j]);
                            row.append(cell);
                        }
                        table.append(row);

                    }
                    $("#dvCSV").html('');
                    $("#dvCSV").append(table);
                }
                reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT#1 -**
I have edited my JS as below and data is getting populated on screen but its really in bad shape. What can be done?

```
$(function () {
    $("#upload").bind("click", function () {
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
        if (regex.test($("#fileUpload").val().toLowerCase())) {
            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
                    var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");

                    //alert(rows);
                    var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(rows);
                    var columnCount = rows[0].length;


                    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                        for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
                            var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                            cell.innerHTML = rows[i][j];
                        }
                    }

                    $("#dvCSV").html('');
                    $("#dvCSV").append(table);
                }
                reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a library that you can import in your project, you should pass the CSV text loaded from your file reader and it will do the math for your and return a JSON object.

```
            csvObjects = CSV.parse(csvText);

            jsonText = JSON.stringify(csvObjects, null, '\t');

            jsonField.value = jsonText;
```

https://github.com/cparker15/csv-to-json/tree/master/src/js